# meta_query: using BETWEEN with floats and/or casting to DECIMAL

Tags: wp-query, post-meta, get-posts

Each post has a lat/lng value attached to it via postmeta. I'm trying to grab all posts within a bounding lat/lng value. Here's the `get_posts` query:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 100,
    'post_type' => 'place',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'places_lat',
            'value' => array($lat_min, $lat_max),
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            //'type' => 'DECIMAL',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'places_lng',
            'value' => array($lng_min, $lng_max),
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            //'type' => 'DECIMAL',
        ),
    ),
));
```

Since postmeta values are stored as strings, I figured I should be casting to `DECIMAL`, but it just seems to trim the decimal value from the string due to the lack of `DECIMAL` arguments/precision parameters.

I did notice the query treats the floats within the `value` array as strings, which could also be another point of failure. Running the compiled query without the quotes around each floating value works as expected.

I'll be using `get_permalink()` on each post. I can run a custom query outside of `get_posts` (via `$wpdb->get_results()`) to properly grab the posts within the bounding box, then loop through the posts and `get_permalink`, but it ends up firing an additional database query per post to build the permalink - not an ideal solution!

Any ideas?

Comment: A sidenote: I would not do a location query on the `postmeta` table, it will be hard to benefit from indexes this way. I once [wrote an example](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/468/optimizing-a-proximity-based-store-location-search-on-a-shared-web-host/2712#2712) that copies post geodata in a separate table with an efficient index, and does the geo queries on that table.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can filter generated SQL and add precision parameters that you need.

Enable filters for `get_posts()` by adding following to query:

```
'suppress_filters' => false,
```

And:

```
add_filter('posts_where','cast_decimal_precision');

function cast_decimal_precision( $where ) {

    return str_replace('DECIMAL','DECIMAL(10,3)',$where);
}
```

**Update**

With Jan's suggestion:

```
add_filter('get_meta_sql','cast_decimal_precision');

function cast_decimal_precision( $array ) {

    $array['where'] = str_replace('DECIMAL','DECIMAL(10,3)',$array['where']);

    return $array;
}
```

Comment: You can even use a more specific filter: [`get_meta_sql`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.1/wp-includes/meta.php#L445), since the taxonomy query part is created in `_get_meta_sql()`. This is also unaffected by `suppress_filters`, so you don't have to disable that.

Comment: Thanks Rarst, and thanks again Jan! I think the best option in this case is moving the lat/lng values into their own table for better indexing.

Comment: tried both solutions and it looks like it compares them as strings with single quotes (wp 3.1.1), any ideas on that? trying raw sql did work though.

Comment: @Amit nothing I can really guess here... Such is usually long debug mess with query-related code.

Answer (score 5):

As of 3.8 ([see track](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23033)) the precision can be added to the cast type like so:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 100,
    'post_type' => 'place',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'places_lat',
            'value' => array($lat_min, $lat_max),
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type' => 'DECIMAL(10,3)',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'places_lng',
            'value' => array($lng_min, $lng_max),
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type' => 'DECIMAL(10,3)',
        ),
    ),
));
```