# Custom query with DECIMAL(5,2)

Tags: customization, meta-query

I want to know if there is a way to DECIMAL (5,2) instead of DECIMAL in meta_query

Answer (score 3):

Answer taken from here: [meta_query: using BETWEEN with floats and/or casting to DECIMAL](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14163/meta-query-using-between-with-floats-and-or-casting-to-decimal)

```
add_filter('get_meta_sql','cast_decimal_precision');

function cast_decimal_precision( $array ) {

    $array['where'] = str_replace('DECIMAL','DECIMAL(5,2)',$array['where']);

    return $array;
}
```

Comment: I can't use "meta_query" like this : `'meta_query' => array(
  array(
   'key' => 'color',
   'value' => 'blue',
   'compare' => 'NOT LIKE'
  ),
  array(
   'key' => 'price',
   'value' => array( 20, 100 ),
   'type' => 'numeric',
   'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
  )
 )` with get_posts()

Comment: why can't you use get_posts()?