# What is the best practice to localize content? (Geographic not langauge)

Tags: content, customization

I have a website that needs to display state-specific versions, for a few states. Obviously, I will need to parse the IP address to gain geographic information. Before I start making that plug-in, I figured I'd shoot a question out to the collective.

To further explain my situation, the website has a different "version", depending on if customers are coming to it from Texas, California, New York and Canada. The language will be English throughout, but the content for Texas is different (think: compliance) from California.

I was thinking of using a splash page (cringe) with a drop-down, should all else fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess [this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/468/optimizing-a-proximity-based-store-location-search-on-a-shared-web-host) will steal you more than a day. After reading through it and all the code it contains, you'll be more than happy... or maybe just confused ;)

Comment: Definitely the relevant information I was looking for. I recommend **anybody** looking for some information on GIS with Wordpress to check that out.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people use http://www.maxmind.com/app/region . It is reasonably priced,  up to date and has a decent PHP api ( and other languages).