# Is it possible to wrap Geo Location search around WP_Query?

Tags: wp-query, geo-data, sql

I'll just like to add that I have a current working solution in place and works well but I'm looking for ideas of being able to do it better or cleaner if possible.

We have hundreds of properties in a custom post type with metakey/metavalue holding the properties longitude and latitude co-ordinates.

We allow a visitor to type in a location and a radius to search for those properties in that area. Kind of like a store locator. Here is how I'm doing it at the moment:

```
// Work out square radius
if(!empty($_SESSION['s_property_radius'])) {$dist = $_SESSION['s_property_radius'];}else{$dist = 50;}
$orig_lat = $_SESSION['s_property_address_lat'];
$orig_lon = $_SESSION['s_property_address_lng'];
$lon1 = $orig_lon - $dist / abs( cos( deg2rad( $orig_lat ) ) * 69 );
$lon2 = $orig_lon + $dist / abs( cos( deg2rad( $orig_lat ) ) * 69 );
$lat1 = $orig_lat - ( $dist / 69 );
$lat2 = $orig_lat + ( $dist / 69 );

// Compile a map search query to get all property ID's.
$mapsearchquery = "
            SELECT `t`.`ID`
            , 3956 * 2 * ASIN( SQRT( POWER( SIN( ( ".$orig_lat." - CAST(`t`.`property_address_lat` AS DECIMAL(9,6)) ) * pi() / 180 / 2), 2 ) + COS( ".$orig_lat." * pi() / 180) * COS( CAST(`t`.`property_address_lat` AS DECIMAL(9,6)) * pi() / 180 ) * POWER( SIN( ( ".$orig_lon." - CAST(`t`.`property_address_lng` AS DECIMAL(9,6)) ) * pi() / 180 / 2 ), 2 ) ) ) AS `distance` 
            FROM (

            SELECT `$wpdb->posts`.`ID`
            , MAX(CASE WHEN `$wpdb->postmeta`.`meta_key` = 'chb_homes_for_sale_address_longitude' THEN `$wpdb->postmeta`.`meta_value` END ) AS `property_address_lng`
            , MAX(CASE WHEN `$wpdb->postmeta`.`meta_key` = 'chb_homes_for_sale_address_latitude' THEN `$wpdb->postmeta`.`meta_value` END ) AS `property_address_lat`
            FROM `$wpdb->posts` 
            LEFT JOIN `$wpdb->postmeta` ON ( `$wpdb->posts`.`ID` = `$wpdb->postmeta`.`post_id` ) 
            WHERE `$wpdb->posts`.`post_status` = 'publish' 
            AND `$wpdb->posts`.`post_type` = 'homes-for-sale' 
            GROUP BY `$wpdb->posts`.`ID` 
            HAVING CAST(`property_address_lng` AS DECIMAL(9,6)) BETWEEN '".$lon1."' AND '".$lon2."' AND CAST(`property_address_lat` AS DECIMAL(9,6)) BETWEEN '".$lat1."' AND '".$lat2."'

            ) AS `t`
            HAVING `distance` < ".$dist."
        ";

// Just get the ID's
$mapsearchresults = $wpdb->get_col($mapsearchquery);
```

This returns an array of all post id's that are within the users search parameters. I then past that array to WP_Query to only show posts that have the above ID's using `post__in`. Also I can do other search criteria on the WP_Query afterwards.

In the above query I do a square radius check and I know this could be easily done in WP_Query using `meta_query`. But where I get stuck is running the circle radius check. Is there a way I can wrap this in WP_Query?

Basically what I'm after is trying to do this all in one rather than doing two lots of queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would duplicate the coordinates of the posts in a separate table `(post_id, lat, lon)`, with an index on `(lat, lon)`. With all the joins and the casts I doubt the database can use an efficient index with your query.

I once wrote [an answer to a similar question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/468/optimizing-a-proximity-based-store-location-search-on-a-shared-web-host/2712#2712) using this approach.

Comment: Yeah I saw this. However my code will be somewhat different as my setup in the backend is a little more complicated. But I like the idea of saving the lat lon in another table. For me I think I'll have to add an extra column that stores the post type as I have multiple post types that might have lat lon attached.

Comment: Jan how would I correctly index my separate table? Also taking into account I'll add an additional column for post type. thanks

Comment: @Brady: Well, if you query for posts that have post type "x" and are between certain boundaries for `lat` and `lon`, an index on `(lat, lon, post_type)` should be enough. If you read the database much more than you write to it, I don't think you can have too many indexes :-) MySQL's `EXPLAIN` will be your friend here, but database optimization can also be a good question for the regular Stack Overflow site.

Comment: @Jan: OK I'll put a post up on stack overflow to best optimise this table. But back to my question... By using a different table to do the GEO Data search all that I'm changing is `$mapsearchquery` to a more efficient way. Is it at all possible to incorporate `$mapsearchquery` into WP_Query or the way I'm doing it now using `post__in` the best way?

Comment: @Brady: We'll always have to get the post IDs from the secondary table first, and then use them to get the full post information. You can do this in one query (`WHERE post_id IN (SELECT post_id FROM secondary_table WHERE [geo_stuff])`, or with a join), or first query them and then pass them to the query (`WHERE post_id IN (1, 2, 4, 6)`), and you can do the latter in an integrated way or just in two steps using `post_in`. If this was for a plugin that you distribute to others I would integrate it for simplicity, otherwise... I don't think I would spend the extra effort to "clean it up".

Comment: Yeah I understand this Jan, but what I dont understand is how I get my GEO SQL into the variable WP_Query. I know I can pass and argument that has an array of ID's but it doesnt allow SQL to be passed. Is there a filter I need to use? As for making this for general consumption, thats not the idea, but two of our biggest clients website use geo data like the code I've shown so I thinking at doing some extra work so its reusable somewhat.

Comment: @Brady: Take a look at [`WP_Query::get_posts`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.2/wp-includes/query.php#L1874), it's full of filters you can hook into. `pre_get_posts` is a nice one where you can process extra arguments like `geo_lat`, `get_lon` and replace them with the correct `post__in` by doning the geo query in your filter, or use one of the filters on the `WHERE` part so you can integrate it in the main query. Hook into and dump `posts_request` to see the resulting SQL query.

Comment: I wrote a plugin that extends WP_Query. It takes a user's lat/long as an additional arg, and returns distance, location, lat, and long of each post and returns by distance. https://github.com/fyaconiello/wp-geo-posts