# I have geocoded posts with latitude longitude - How to search by radius?

Tags: geo-data, location-search

I have posts which are geocoded with latitude and longitude from Google. I basically can enter an address in a post custom field and the latitude and longitude are placed into two separate meta fields.

I'd like to create a custom search letting visitors search their zip/postal code and find the nearest locations.

I've found this plugin which does all that bundled in one with custom post types then a search page http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-find-your-nearest/

I was thinking to try and modify it to work with my custom meta fields and only use the search page/function. Does anyone know of any other plugins or methods to create a custom search using postal codes and radiuses from lat / long meta fields

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's [Geo Data Store by our own man, @Brady](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/geo-data-store/). It does a perfect job in one of my installations.

It uses a custom table, that stores only ID, meta ID, lat and lng information, so your queries stay quick and brief, even when your database starts scaling. It got a 5 star rating from my side.

> This plugin is meant to be used by other developers and to be used together with themes and other plugins. Many themes and plugins use WordPress meta data table to store longitude and latitude co-ordinates for posts. While this works fine the meta data table cannot be indexed very well. Let's take for example you have made a custom post type called 'properties'. You create 100,000 posts all attached with latitude and longitude co-ordinates. You want your users to search for those properties in a 50 mile radius for example. Because of the method of which WordPress stores the meta data the query is slow especially when dealing with large amounts of data.

<sup>@Brady in the plugin description.</sup>

Note: There's a bug - related to WP internals - that rows don't delete, when you delete a post. Don't be concerned about it. I tried to work through it with the dev and we didn't get behind it. Anyway: It doesn't harm anything, but you should clean up your tables, before you go live (or test in a local installation), to minimize the amount of non related rows.

Sample code from Scotts pastebin in the comments

```
        // Only do a map search if user submitted one
        if( 2 == $_SESSION['s_doing_property_search'] )
        {
            // Only generate map search results if we don't have any yet or if they are a day out of date
            if( empty( $_SESSION['homes_for_' . $type . '_map_search_results'] ) || $_SESSION['homes_for_' . $type . '_map_search_timestamp'] < strtotime( "-1 Day" ) )
            {
                // Load instance of GeoDataStore
                if ( ! isset( $sc_gds ) )
                    $sc_gds = new sc_GeoDataStore();

                // Just get the ID's of posts in range
                $_SESSION['homes_for_' . $type . '_map_search_results'] = (array) $sc_gds->getPostIDsOfInRange( "homes-for-" . $type, $_SESSION['s_property_radius'], $_SESSION['s_property_address_lat'], $_SESSION['s_property_address_lng'] );

                // Set a timestamp so we don't do this expensive get each page load.
                $_SESSION['homes_for_' . $type . '_map_search_timestamp'] = time();
            }

            // We we have no results then set an array just one that will trigger no posts found.
            if( empty( $_SESSION['homes_for_' . $type . '_map_search_results'] ) )
                $query->set( 'post__in', array(1) );
            else
                $query->set( 'post__in', $_SESSION['homes_for_' . $type . '_map_search_results'] );
        }
```

Comment: I was just about to recommend this :) I'm working on a newer version that fixes the problems the current plugin has but it wont support separate meta fields for lat/lng. So if you can program your code to use a single meta field separating lat/lng with a `,` then the new version of the plugin will work for you.

Comment: @Brady Please drop me a note in chat, or a mail, when you're done :)

Comment: Thanks Kaiser I had seen this plugin as well but I'm not at all good with PHP. At best I was hoping to modify some functions to work with my existing meta fields. I understand it's storing data in an efficient way. I'll only have a few hundred posts maybe 1k at most with geocodes. Any idea where I can find sample code to search by radius?

Comment: At the end of the plugin are two template tags, that you can use.

Comment: @Brady looking at your plugin's code now, I didn't realize it had built in distance functions. Any chance you can share some front end code, just looking to loop through all posts checking distance against lat and lng fields. Once I have the query I can display the posts as needed

Comment: I see the functions, last question should I put the `sc_geodatastore_meta_keys` into my functions.php? To associate my meta tag names

Comment: yes functions.php would be fine

Comment: Here is some example usage: http://pastebin.com/kQQJc3XA I'm running that code inside `pre_get_posts` filter

Comment: @Brady any advice on how to use WordPress default search if anything other than a postal code is entered? So that posts can be searched by keyword as usual?

Comment: @Anagio have you had any luck getting that pastebin code to work? I'm a bit out in left field with it.